# Osgeo Welcome window

Tags: ubuntu, osgeo

Is it possible to disable OsGeo Live 7.0 Welcome window? It annoys me a bit appearing each time I Run the system.

Solved by:
menu->settings->settings manager->session and startup->"Application Autostart"->uncheck the message appearance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the file `/home/user/.config/autostart/welcome_message.desktop`.

That will do the trick.